# Intestate succession in Utah: Parent and Siblings

Tags: real-estate, wills, utah, inheritance, succession

Joe owned a home. He died without a will. His survivors are a mother and six siblings.

Do I understand correctly that the mother inherits everything and the siblings nothing? Here is a link to the UT code that led me to this conclusion:

[Utah - Section 103 Share of heirs other than surviving spouse](https://le.utah.gov/xcode/Title75/Chapter2/75-2-S103.html?v=C75-2-S103_1800010118000101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Yes](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/intestate-succession-utah.html), the mother inherits the estate

Note that the estate is not "everything".

Comment: What do you mean by it is not everything?

Comment: @Viktor not everything you own passes through your estate. Some things (e.g. life insurance, retirement plans) pass directly to the beneficiaries.